# getting elements to stick in an array in java (mock bookstore project)

Tags: java, arrays

new to java here. Having trouble with multiple parts of this project to make a mock bookstore. where i'm at right now is correctly getting new books to stick in the books[] array past the first one i put in. when i run methods "listTitles" and "listBooks" in the bookstore class, it only show me the first book that i'ved logged. in addition to that i'm having trouble implementing two other methods: the "addNewBook" method and the "sellBook" method also in the bookstore class. if your on this page, please let me know what i'm doing/not doing to get those methods to work. you'll see commented code for the intended parameters of each method. sorry if its a bit of a mess, Thanks for your time.

#### Class: MyBookStore

```
public class MyBookstore {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Bookstore mybookstore = new Bookstore();

        int user_choice;

        do {

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("1) Add a book to the stock");
            System.out.println("2) Sell a book in stock");
            System.out.println("3) List the titles of all the books in stock");
            System.out.println("4) List all the information about the books in stock");
            System.out.println("5) Print out the gross income of the bookstore");
            System.out.println("6) Quit");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("please select one of the six options");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("your choice:");
            user_choice = s.nextInt();
            switch (user_choice) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Enter a title");
                    String title = s.next();
                    System.out.println("how many pages is the book?");
                    int pages = s.nextInt();

                    System.out.println("how much does this book cost?");
                    double price = s.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("how many of these books are there in stock?");
                    int stock = s.nextInt();

                    Book c = new Book(title, pages, price, stock);
                    mybookstore.addNewBook(c);

                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Selling books:");
                    System.out.println("Enter the title...");
                    String an = s.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter a quantity");
                    int da = s.nextInt();
                    mybookstore.sellBook(an, da);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    mybookstore.listTitles();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    mybookstore.listBooks();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    mybookstore.getIncome();

                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("please select from one of the six options");

            }
        } while (user_choice != '6');
    }
}
```

#### Class: Bookstore

```
class Bookstore {

    private Book[] books;    // all the books in this bookstore
    private int totalBooks;   // the number of books in this bookstore
    private double grossIncome;   //the gross income of the bookstore (will be incremented when books are sold)

    public Bookstore() {

        books = new Book[100];
        totalBooks = 0;
        grossIncome = 0;

    }
    //If it is already in stock, simply ask the user to enter how many extra books to stock, and then do so. 

    public void addNewBook(Book b) {
        books[totalBooks] = b;
        totalBooks++;

        for (int i = 0; i < totalBooks; i++) {
            if (b.getTitle() == books[i].getTitle()) {
                String name = b.getTitle();
                Scanner m = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("books is already in stock, how many additonal books would you like to stock?");
                int stock = m.nextInt();


                addBookQuantity(name, stock);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("book has been logged");
        return;
    }

    public void addBookQuantity(String title, int quantity){

        // Adds quantity number of books to the book already in stock in the Bookstore object with
        // the title title. If the book is not in the Bookstore object, nothing is done.

        for (int i =0; i<totalBooks; i++) {
            if (title == books[i].getTitle()) {
                books[i].addQuantity(quantity);
                System.out.println("quantity added successfully");
                return;
            }
    }
        System.out.println("book not found.");
    }

    // Returns true if quantity or more copies of a book with the title title are contained in the Bookstore object.
    public boolean inStock(String title, int quantity){
        for (int i =0; i<totalBooks; i++) {
            if (title == books[i].getTitle()) {
                if (quantity <= books[i].getQuantity()) {return true;}
                else {return false;}
            }
        }
        return false;       
    }

        // Executes selling quantity number of books from the Bookstore object with the title title to the
        // buyer. The Bookstore object is changed to reflect the sale. The gross income of the bookstore is incremented 
        //accordingly. The method returns true is the sale was executed successfully, false otherwise.
        public boolean sellBook(String title, int quantity){
             for ( int i = 0; i < totalBooks;) {
                    if (title == books[i].getTitle()  ) {
                        books[i].subtractQuantity(quantity);
                        double l = books[i].getPrice();
                        double profit = l*quantity;
                        grossIncome = grossIncome + profit;
                      //rework this
                        System.out.println("books sold. Total store profits:" + profit);

                    }

             }
        return false;//System.out.println("Book not in stock");
        }


    public void listTitles(){
        // Lists all of the titles of the books in the Bookstore object.
        for (int i = 0; i<totalBooks; ) {
            System.out.println(books[i].getTitle()); 


                return;
            }
        }

    // Lists all of the information about the books in the Bookstore object. 
    public void listBooks(){

        for (int i = 0; i<totalBooks;) {
            System.out.println(books[i].toString()); 


              return;
            }



    }

    // Returns the total gross income of the Bookstore object.
    public double getIncome(){
        return grossIncome;


    }
}
```

#### Class: Book

```
class Book {

    private String title;
    private int numOfPages;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;

    public Book(String theTitle, int pages, double cost, int num) {
        title = theTitle;
        numOfPages = pages;
        price = cost;
        num = quantity;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Title:" + title + "\nNumber of pages: " + numOfPages + "\nPrice:" + price + "\nquantity left:" + getQuantity();
    }

    public void subtractQuantity(int amount) {
        quantity = quantity - amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, you may want to consider an ArrayList.  This can grow dynamically.  Your current method limits to 100 books.

Comment: @BlackBox Your editing has rendered the code non executable. You've also managed to remove the method that the OP asked his original question on. Please be careful with the editing and only format for better readability. Don't take stuff away.

Comment: I've rolled back the edit. Try again.

Comment: @nickecarlo, all my edit did was format his code and clearly outlined where 1 class started and another ended. All you needed to do was place them all in 1 Java file to work. Furthermore, the question asked did not require anyone to compile the code, only understand it, which is now harder again.

Comment: @BlackBox check your edit of the Bookstore class. You basically deleted all of its methods except one. You probably made a mistake but it appears under your name as an edit made by you. Either way, Joe Frambach has thankfully reverted it back to its original form.

Comment: Apologies, it must have been a copy & paste error, I had no idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
private Book[] books;    // all the books in this bookstore
private int totalBooks;
```

This is a double administration, and if not all books are getting listed, my bet is that `totalBooks = 1` but `books.length` is `> 1`.

The quickest solution would be to drop `totalBooks` and to use `books.length` everywhere.

Aside from that I'd recommend you use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead to store the books.

Comment: i'm also trying to get the addNewBook() method to filter if the user puts in the name of the same book twice. would i do that in the switch statement by using an IF statement? i tried doing that but i can't figure out how to access the books[] array outside the bookstore class. or would i filter in directly in the addNewBooks{} method?

Comment: Is a matter of taste. You can put a method `hasBook(Book book)` in your `Bookstore` class that checks if a book is already in the books array and then you can report this to the user. Or you can filter in `addNewBooks` or you can use a `Set` to store the books.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void listTitles(){
        // Lists all of the titles of the books in the Bookstore object.
        for (int i = 0; i<totalBooks; ) {
            System.out.println(books[i].getTitle()); 


            return;
        }
 }
```

Should be:

```
public void listTitles(){
        // Lists all of the titles of the books in the Bookstore object.
        for (int i = 0; i<totalBooks; i++) {
            System.out.println(books[i].getTitle()); 
        }
        return;
 }
```

The reason it only shows the first one is because the way you have your code currently the loop would only execute once and then hit the return statement. return means "return to main" essentially so the loop in this case is useless.

I moved your return statement out of the loop and added the "i++" to your loop. It should work fine now.

Of course as others have suggested, ArrayList may be better suited for this but I'm assuming you're trying to learn Java so its better you stick with what you've picked for now and understand where you're making mistakes. Fixing your mistakes is the best way to learn.

Do keep ArrayLists in mind for later though.

**-------------------------Regarding a question in the comments below--------------------**

As I said I still haven't had the time to look at it and test it but here's a clue I can offer so you can work on your methods:

```
public void addNewBook(Book b){
     books[totalBooks] = b;
        totalBooks ++; 

        for (int i =0; i<totalBooks; i++) {
            if ( b.getTitle() == books[i].getTitle()) {
                String name = b.getTitle();
                Scanner m = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("books is already in stock, how many additonal books would you like to stock?");
                int stock = m.nextInt();


               addBookQuantity(name, stock);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("book has been logged");
                return;


    }
```

Your method above starts off by adding books to your array. You might want to change the method thusly:

```
public void addNewBook(Book b) {
    if (books.length != 0) {
        // check if the title is already added
        for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
             if (books[i].getTitle().equals(b.getTitle())
                   // dont add book title again
             else
                  // add book title
        }
    } else {
        // add book title
    }
}
```

As flup already suggested though you could use a Set and then convert the Set back to an array. Sets only store unique values and Java has a method for sets that will convert it to an array.

Comment: ah thank you! what a simple fix. i'm also trying to get the addNewBook() method to filter if the user puts in the name of the same book twice. would i do that in the switch statement by using an IF statement? i tried doing that but i can't figure out how to access the books[] array outside the bookstore class. or would i filter in directly in the addNewBooks{} method?

Comment: @user2162004 I haven't looked at the whole thing again but quickly looking at your addNewBooks{} method shows that you're using == to compare Strings. == only shows if the memory location where these Strings are stored is the same or not (which it is not). What you want to use is equals() to compare Strings. More on that here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html Once I get the time I will go over your code and then update my answer.